# Why is Some Text Bold?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I'm building a WPF installer and I have two radio buttons, for installing and uninstalling:

[image: Radio buttons]

Here is the XAML for each button, just for reference:

Install button:

```
<RadioButton Content="Install" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="42,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.591,2.133" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
```

Uninstall button:

```
<RadioButton Content="Uninstall" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="42,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" 
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.591,2.133" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
```

Now as you can see from the code, the buttons are basically the same, except for one says install, the other says uninstall, and their positioning is different. However, when the program is run, I get this result:

[image: Install and Uninstall buttons in action]

Any ideas as to why it is making the uninstall button bold, and how I can fix this?

**EDIT:** Here's the entire code for the program if you're interested. I hadn't gotten very far in before I noticed this problem:

```
<Window x:Class="Installer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Installer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Tic-Tac-Toe Installer" Height="283.159" Width="529.765">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,2,2">
        <RadioButton Content="Install" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,90,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" RenderTransformOrigin="0.591,2.133" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>
        <Label Content="Please select to install or uninstall Tic-Tac-Toe." Margin="27,23,-75,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="22" Width="475" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Button Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="427,214,-60,-37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="16"/>
        <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" Margin="331,214,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="16" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.734,0.499"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Uninstall" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" RenderTransformOrigin="0.591,2.133" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here's the outcome:

[image: Full display]

Now, you may notice, that in this image, all of the text is bold. Whereas before, only the title ("Please select to install or uninstall Tic-Tac-Toe") and the Uninstall text was bold, but I haven't changed anything!

Comment: I would believe some setting is applied to their parents causing the difference. Please [edit] your question and include where those buttons are declared

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a duplicated "Uninstall" button tag? This sometimes happens when two identical text blocks are positioned on top of each other.

Comment: @Impworks No, there isn't an extra Uninstall button, and even more interesting, now the install button is bold, and I didn't change anything! See the edit for the entire code and outcome.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't think so, but I did upload all of my code and the outcome.

Comment: There is not much we can do if you can't provide two code samples that show both outcomes. The way it is now we can only guess. Also: the text isn't bold; its size is just larger than what is normally used in UIs.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd You're right! When I downsized the text, it made it look normal! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The text is not bold. Its size is just larger than we are used to in UIs.

To make the text regular size remove the FontSize attributes completely.